# Intermittent problems connecting to a network storage device

Tags: networking

My partner has a lot of difficulty connecting to a network attached storage device from her laptop, connecting to it via a wireless network.

The NAS ( A Seagate Central Mediadrive 1TB) is attached to the network via cable to a WN2500RP Netgear Wireless Extender.

We access the drive via Windows File explorer by using \mediadrive\

The problem is that her laptop will lose connection to the NAS after some time, and she won't be able to connect again until the laptop ( Windows 10) is rebooted. Sometimes not even then.

Just now she was unable to connect to it via file explorer, but was able to ping it ( 10.0.0.128 ) and was able to bring up the webconsole for it. I was able to connect to it ( I have a wired connection to the modem\router) during this time.

Whilst i have been typing this up, we can now connect to the mediadrive from the laptop.

Whats going on?

What can I do to help troubleshoot the problem for her?

Comment: Is it just the NAS that has problems or are there other network dropouts?

Comment: the wifi extender/bridge is suspect in this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a wireless instability issue. Either her laptop or the extender is having issues with the wireless connection. Make sure the laptop's drivers are up to date. Between the two, the extender is the first suspect.

If possible, I'd start with replacing the extender for a few days, as a test period.